# Genimotion Эмулятор + localhost

Tags: java, android, socket.io

Доброго всем вечера, изучаю тему socketIO и сейчас столкнулся с проблемой соединения моего эмулятора с локальным сервером NODE.JS. Помогите пожалуйста с присоединением сети..
Вот код Activity:

```
SocketIO socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new SocketIO("http://127.0.0.1:889");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
            System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
            System.out.println("an Error occured");
            socketIOException.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnect() {
            System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnect() {
            System.out.println("Connection established");
        }

        @Override
        public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
            System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
        }
    });

    // This line is cached until the connection is establisched.
    socket.send("Hello Server!");
```

А вот код сервера:

```
var port = 889;
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Порт " + port + " открыт");
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("Socket connection: " + socket.id);
});
```

Переходя из браузера по адресу `http://127.0.0.1:889` с ПК, страничка открывается и создаётся сокет соединение о чём свидетельствуют мои логи...

`Порт 889 открыт
Socket connection: /#iqVP6dOx7pgo02jiAAAA`

...но вот как запустить эту же процедуру на Android? 
Использую Wi-Fi роутер, компьютер подключён к интернету через кабель, в эмуляторе интернет соединение присутствует. В манифесте прописано следующее:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>`

При запуске апликашки, в лог падает следующее:

```
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio I/System.out: an Error occured
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err: io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:322)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at io.socket.IOConnection.access$600(IOConnection.java:39)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:199)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 889) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:131)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:313)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     ... 2 more
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:208)
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio W/System.err:     ... 16 more
03-12 10:54:40.338 24442-24468/com.example.aseke.socketio I/io.socket: Cleanup
```

P.S.  по адресу `http://10.0.x.x` - с эмулятора тоже перепробовал несколько вариантов

P.S.S. локальный адрес подобрал методом тыка..но теперь при запуске программы, после ip адреса, почему то подставляются директории /socket.io/1/
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.0.104:889/socket.io/1/

Не могу понять в чём дело

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - это сам эмулятор. И проблема, видимо, описана в постскриптумскриптум, только никаких данных о проблеме нет.

Comment: 10.0.3.2  пробовали?